# Managing Controllers from MobX in Flutter

Tags: flutter, controller, store, mobx

I am using MobX as state management to save myself from using stateful widgets but some of the screens involves controllers and those are the only components forcing me to make my widget stateful. Rest i am already handling well with the MobX Stores. I was wondering if i could **safely** manage and dispose my controllers from the mobx store and also if i could make the store generic so that i can manage all my controllers (several controller i am using like PageController, TextEditingController and ScrollController) from the same store?

Answer (score 0):

In MobX you can define your controllers in store and when you do dependency injection using Provider you can dispose there means ones screen is remove from widget tree it will be dispose and by default store also dispose that once store is dispose. You can't make generics of store.

You can also visit official documentation of [MobX](https://mobx.netlify.app/)

```
route_generator.dart

return Provider(
    create: (context) => YourStore(),
    dispose: (context,value){
        //dispose your controller here
       }
    MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const YourUIPage()
        ),
      );
```